# All entities are being retrieved on startup for some mysterious reason

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Mysterious EF Core issue detected while debugging application startup: every `DbSet` property getter in the context is being called (in alphabetical order based on `DbSet` property name), and every row/entity in the database is being instantiated!

`DbContext` configurarion:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Startup.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}
```

Service configuration:

```
    services.AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>();
```

I tried fixing the issue by adding

```
optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
```

to the `DbContext` configuration but it turned out it requires that I mark every navigation property as `virtual`, and I got a big big number of navigation properties. *I even made myself a WinForms tool that adds the `virtual` modifier to navigation properties - but using proxies caused other issues in my project*.

Nevertheless, either I use lazy loading proxies or not, I believe this must not be the way Entityframework works. Looking forward to any help towards identifying and solving the problem.

Environment:

- Asp.net Core 2.1
- EntityframeworkCore 2.1.4
- Visual Studio 2017 (15.8.6)
- C# 7.3

Comment: Can you please provide code from Startup.cs and Program.cs.  It's likely another service doing this.

Comment: @Brad Could `Identity` core cause this? I noticed that this behavior occurs only with authenticated requests.

Comment: Hang on...you say it happens *while debugging*.  If you have lazy loading enabled and you're inspecting `ProjectDbContext` at a breakpoint then that will trigger loading each `DbSet<T>` because they are public properties.

Comment: @Brad No, I'm currently disabling lazy loading; however, why would that trigger the loading of each `DbSet<T>`? Also, all my entities do inherit from base class; if I set a break point on the base entity's constructor, it gets hit for each single entity in the database - whilst the project at the current phase never actually use these tables.